# FreeIPA users can't see new custom attributes

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I have added some new custom attributes to my FreeIPA and so far I was using the admin account to check them in the WebUI.
But today I accessed the WebUI using a regular user account and I was surprised to see that the new attributes are not visible. when I used "inspect elements" to view the page code I found the attribute's code as this:

```
<dev class="widget text-widget" name="bloodtype" style="display: none;">...</dev>
```

note that the attribute is still visible for the admin.

attribute schema:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.1.1.591
  NAME 'bloodtype'
  DESC 'Employee Blood type'
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE
  X-ORIGIN 'Oracle Unified Directory Server'
  USAGE userApplications )
```

Object class:

```
objectclasses: ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.8.61.11 NAME 'customPerson' SUP person STRUCTURAL MAY bloodtype X-ORIGIN ( 'Extending FreeIPA' 'user defined' ) )
```

python plugin:

```
from ipalib.plugins import user
from ipalib.parameters import Str
from ipalib import _
def validate(ugettext,value):
    if value not in ['A','B','AB','O']:
    return _("Blood type must be either A, B, AB or O.")
user.user.takes_params = user.user.takes_params + (
    Str('bloodtype?',validate,
        cli_name='bloodtype',
        label=_('Blood Type'),
    ),
)
user.user.default_attributes.append('bloodtype')
```

javascript plugin:

```
define([
    'freeipa/phases',
    'freeipa/user'],
    function(phases, user_mod) {
    // helper function
        function get_item(array, attr, value) {
            for (var i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++) {
                if (array[i][attr] === value) return array[i];
            }
            return null;
        }
    var plugin = {};
    plugin.add_fields = function() {
        var facet = get_item(user_mod.entity_spec.facets, '$type', 'details');
        var section = get_item(facet.sections, 'name', 'identity');
        section.fields.push({
            $type:'radio',
            options:[{label:'A',value:'A'},{label:'B',value:'B'},{label:'AB',value:'AB'},{label:'O',value:'O'}],
            label:'Blood type',
            name:'bloodtype'
        });
        return true;
    };
    phases.on('customization', plugin.add_fields);
    return plugin;
});
```

What is the problem and how can I allow all users to view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add the new attribute to ACI.

You can modify ACI in cn=users,cn=accounts,dn=example,=dn=com directly

or you can add new attribute into 'managed_permissions' in the user class, for permission you want to allow to access them.
You need to run ipa-ldap-updater --upgrade after that.

or you can create a new ACI permission and add it to existing privileges.

Comment: I added the attribute to the ACI using an ldif schema depending on the examples in [link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/Managing_Access_Control-Creating_ACIs_Manually.html) but it didn't change anything

Comment: Ok it worked, I added the attribute into a permission and gave it to the user. Thank you for your help.